# GCC - how to issue a warning or error if a function gets defined

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a `DEBUG` macro which either logs a debug message, or is a no-op, depending on whether another macro `__DISABLE_LOGGING__` is defined. However, I still want to get compiler warnings and errors for calls to `DEBUG` when it is a no-op (for example, I want to get the warnings from -Wformat about argument types not matching the format string). As such, I have provided a definition for DEBUG that looks something like the following:

```cpp
#ifndef __DISABLE_LOGGING__

#define DEBUG( fmt, args... )           \
    log( "%s: " fmt, __FUNCTION__, ##args );

#else

[[gnu::format(printf, 1, 2), gnu::error("This is a fake function")]]
int dummy_printf ( const char * format, ... );

#define DEBUG( fmt, args... )           \
    /* NOP */ (void)sizeof( dummy_printf( fmt, ##args ) );

#endif
```

Side-note: By wrapping the call to `dummy_printf` in a `sizeof`, I can prevent the calls to `DEBUG` from affecting the compiled code.

Since the declaration for `log()` is also wrapped in a `#ifndef __DISABLE_LOGGING__`, I couldn't use it in the NOP. Similarly, I can't use printf because I can't guarantee printf will be visible in the code that calls DEBUG. As such I had to define a dummy printf function with the gnu::format attribute that I could call.

Since `dummy_printf` is only there to provide the function signature for printf-type format checking, I want to prevent it from getting called or defined. I can mostly prevent calls to it through the gnu::error attribute, but I can't find any way of getting gcc/clang to print a warning/error if the function gets defined.

Comment: Note that `__DISABLE_LOGGING__` is a reserved identifier. So, unless it is some implementation defined macro documented by your target system, you should not define such macro yourself.

Comment: A few ideas come to mind. They require some research. There's an attribute one can use to warn if a function's return value is not used. So that, and: have your debug function return a dummy class with a private constructor and destructor. It can't be constructed. It can't be destructed. If the debug function gets defined, it has no way of constructing the return value. Whatever calls the debug function must use its return value, but has no way to destroy it.

Comment: @eerorika the `__DISABLE_LOGGING__` macro is part of existing code I didn't write

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's a good idea, but then you have a class that shouldn't get used. You've just moved the problem from a dummy function to a dummy class. Also, defining a whole class for something small like this is a little overkill.

Comment: You can't possibly use a class anywhere, if it has a constructor that nobody can access. Furthermore, helper classes are used all over the place. Just take a peek into your C++ library's headers.